How to apply for UK's Global Talent Visa Stage 1?
I'm currently in the process of applying for the Global Talent Visa, but I have incorrectly applied for the Stage 2 visa. I need help finding the correct form to apply for Stage 1.
Difference between Stage 1 and Stage 2
To apply for the Global Talent visa one must first apply for the Stage 1 Visa, this gives the user an identification number that they can give to the endorsement body.
Once the endorsement body provides an endorsement, you can apply for the Stage 2 visa, which, if it is approved, gives you the Global Talent visa.
My problem
I can't find any way to apply for the Stage 1. I have read every document I found, contacted all the services I could find available but I haven't been able to find the correct link to apply for the Stage 1, I have only found the links for Stage 2.
When applying in the official government website: https://www.gov.uk/global-talent/apply-from-outside-the-uk you have to fill the following form (find image attached):

But this form is for individuals who already have an endorsement (or a prize) so I can't use this as it is a Stage 2 application.
At the same time, if I try to get my endorsement through tech nation's page: http://technation.io/visa/apply they require a Stage 1 Unique Application Number for my application.
I'm stuck in a loop where I can't apply for the visa because I don't have an endorsement, and I can't apply for an endorsement because I don't have a visa.
Does anyone knows how to apply for Stage 1?

This site is about short term travel like vacations. We have another site called [expatriates.se] which is for living and working abroad. That site is a better fit for this question and will probably be moved there.

Found it!
The link is https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/global-talent-endorsement
The link was available in https://www.gov.uk/global-talent-digital-technology/apply-for-endorsement:

